# One of --module-version or --hash-dependencies without module-info.class error getting while packaging as jar in jdk 9

Tags: java, jar, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am exploring [Project Jigsaw @ JDK 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), almost all Java developers are thinking of how Oracle going to bring modularity for Java 9.

I have created a sample java project, code got compiled without any error.

Below is generated byte code files and its structure

```
$ tree mods/dictionary.spi/
mods/dictionary.spi/
├── dictionary
│   ├── DictionaryService.class
│   └── spi 
│       └── Dictionary.class
└── module-info.class
2 directories, 3 files
```

I tried to create jar files for the above class files as stated below.

```
$ /opt/jigsaw-jdk-9/bin/jar --create --file lib/dictionaryspi.jar --module-version=1.0 mods/dictionary.spi/ .
```

**One of --module-version or --hash-dependencies without module-info.class**

Much appreciated if anyone gives best solution for this error.

Comment: Please mark an answer to this if it was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Your command is missing the "change directory" parameter:

```
$ /opt/jigsaw-jdk-9/bin/jar \
    --create \
    --file lib/dictionaryspi.jar \
    --module-version=1.0 \
    -C mods/dictionary.spi/ .
```

Note the `-C` before the directory that contains your classes.

Comment: No problem. It would be nice if you would accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Note that the `lib` directory needs to exist or the `jar` command is going to fail. They fixed `javac` to create non-existing output directories, but didn't consider making the same common sense fix to the `jar` command. Go figure!